# The most efficient way to build a deep nested dictionary from a list of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries `l`, each of them is a simple 1-level dictionary with the same keys `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.
Now I want to build a nested dictionary from `l` in this shape (`i` is an member of `l`):

```
{
    i['a']: {
        i['b']: {
            i['c']: {
                i['d']: some_value,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right now I'm using this snippet:

```
tmp = {}
for i in l:
    if not i['a'] in tmp:
        tmp[i['a']] = {}
    if not i['b'] in tmp[i['a']]:
        tmp[i['a']][i['b']] = {}
    if not i['c'] in tmp[i['a']][i['b']]:
        tmp[i['a']][i['b']][i['c']] = {}
    tmp[i['a']][i['b']][i['c']][i['d']] = some_value
```

Is that the most efficient way if the original list is huge?

Answer (score 0):

I would nest several `collection.defaultdict` objects to avoid key testing and use native code instead of slow python code. If a key doesn't exist, a default dictionary is created, except for the deeper one which can just be a `dict`:

```
tmp = collections.defaultdict(lambda : collections.defaultdict(lambda : collections.defaultdict(dict)))
for i in l:
    tmp[i['a']][i['b']][i['c']][i['d']] = some_value
```

you can shorten the definition by aliasing the object name:

```
dd = collections.defaultdict
tmp = dd(lambda : dd(lambda : dd(dict)))
```

Comment: However, when I use [this code](https://gist.github.com/tgquan67/d4608154f23b2892605aceb68a4f91f4) to test the time, it's usually that defaultdict is much slower than manual key testing.